# Blog App not saving attributes to database upon form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form-for

I am following a guide to build a blog with rails, simple `Post` model with title and body.

I am using simple form and upon form submission to create a new post, the post saves created_at and updated_at values, but not the actual content submitted in the form.

I have attempted removing the code for simple form and using Rails native form_for. This DOES save all values to the database. I am new to simple form, not certain whether or not I am using it correctly.

Here is the console record:

```
    Started POST "/posts" for ::1 at 2019-08-17 13:51:01 -0500
    Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",    "authenticity_token"=>"qY8kYZxVIMBL8lzHYuQ4qOu6nXsTGLWCRhLPJ2eiAU8EyzR61fZppAFBYmgcm3rx02FYAHcCgFBVlUyDTLtDGA==", "post"=>{"title"=>"Simple Form Test", "body"=>"<p>Test Test Test</p>\r\n"}, "commit"=>"Create Post"}
    (0.0ms)  begin transaction
      SQL (3.3ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES         (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2019-08-17 18:51:01.325736"], ["updated_at", "2019-        08-17 18:51:01.325736"]]
       (7.7ms)  commit transaction
    Redirected to http://localhost:3000/posts/3
    Completed 302 Found in 28ms (ActiveRecord: 11.1ms)
```

Here is the form:

```
    <%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
      <% if @post.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2>
    <%= "#{pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this post from being saved:" %>
  </h2>
  <ul>
    <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li>
        <%= msg %>
      </li>
              <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.input :title, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.input :body, :as => :ckeditor, input_html: {:ckeditor =>         {:toolbar => 'FULL'}}, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.button :submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Here is the controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_post, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :delete]

  # Index action to render all posts
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # New action for creating post
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # Create action saves the post into database
  def create
    @post = Post.new
    if @post.save(post_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created post!"
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Error creating new post!"
      render :new
    end
  end

  # Edit action retrives the post and renders the edit page
  def edit
  end

  # Update action updates the post with the new information
  def update
    if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated post!"
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Error updating post!"
      render :edit
    end
  end

  # The show action renders the individual post after retrieving the the id
  def show
  end

  # The destroy action removes the post permanently from the database
  def destroy
    if @post.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully deleted post!"
      redirect_to posts_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Error updating post!"
    end
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
  end

  def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end
Hopin
```

g to be able to create posts with body and title, and learn more about simple form.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are we to guess at the code in your controller?

Comment: Sorry, knew I forgot something! Added now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote `@post = Post.new` without pass your parameters to your object, so when you save you object you save an empty object.

It should be either :

`@post = Post.new(post_params)`

Or directly

`@post = Post.create(post_params)`